# Why doesn't the "this" keyword work here?

Tags: javascript, this

```
<button onclick="test()">Will it work?</button>


function test() {
this.innerHTML = "It works!";
}
```

The button calls the function test, so it should be affected by the "this" keyword.

Comment: What do you think **this** should be?  Looking at the code as is, **this** is referencing the global object, not the button element.  [More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it to the function

```
<button onclick="test(this)">

function test(btn) {
    console.log(btn);
    btn.innerHTML = "it worked";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KV27W/1/

Comment: @user3289319 Check the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this):

> Inside a function, the value of this depends on how the function is called.
>
> **Simple call**
>
> ```
> function f1(){
>   return this;
> }
>
> f1() === window; // global object
> ```
>
> In this case, the value of `this` is not set by the call. Since the code is not in strict mode, the value of `this` must always be an object so it defaults to the global object.

So, whenever you call a function as `func()`, `this` refers to the global object. And that's exactly what you are doing here:

```
onclick="test()"
```

You are right that `this` inside an event handler refers to the element the handler is bound to, but `test` is not the event handler, it is in the *body* of an event handler. The handler generated from the attribute value will look like

```
function(event) {
    test();
}
```

So you see, it's a "simple call", so there is no question about what `this` refers to.

---

If you want to have it refer to the button, then you can use [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), to call `test` and explicitly set `this` to the passed value:

```
onclick="test.call(this)"
```